# USB 2.0 Device Signal Quality xHCI Testing

Tags: usb, usb-device

I haven't run this test in 3-4 years and when I did it was the EHCI version. If I understand correctly, I need to use the xHCI version because my host controller is a new-ish laptop that supports up to 3.2. However, the xHCI version of the software tool looks substantially different than the EHCI version. All I want to do is generate an eye diagram, but can't find the test that simply loops the device descriptor like I'm used to. There are dozens and dozens of tests. Can anyone walk me through this high-level? Have I got it completely wrong? I tried the EHCI tool as well but it can't find my host controller.

Comment: If you just want to generate an eye diagram, don't you just need to transmit data?

Comment: Again,there could be a LOT I am forgetting, but I thought I needed to get my host controller to loop the device descriptor so that my Keysight scope (which is running the USB compliance software) will generate an eye diagram. Or am I confusing myself?

Comment: If you need to do some kind of USB standard test, then you'll have to run the right test. If you just want to generate an eye diagram (without a specific test), you can do this with any kind of data transfer.